# How do I transfer output of animation R package on a beamer frame

Tags: beamer, r, animate

I have the following R code from `animation` package that generates a random number which adds random number generated one after the other on display on `R` terminal.

```
library("animation")
brownian.motion():
function(n=10,xlim=c(-20,20),ylim=c(-20,20))
{
  x=rnorm(n)
  y=rnorm(n)
  for (i in seq_len(ani.options("nmax"))) {
   dev.hold()
    plot(x,y,xlim = xlim,ylim = ylim)
    text(x,y)
    x=x+rnorm(n)
    y=y+rnorm(n)
  }
}
```

I want the result of this R code to be in a beamer frame just as it is being displayed on `R` terminal.

I tried the below code as my MWE but it did not work

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
 \begin{frame}
%beginning of R code
library("animation")
brownian.motion():
function(n=10,xlim=c(-20,20),ylim=c(-20,20))
{
  x=rnorm(n)
  y=rnorm(n)
  for (i in seq_len(ani.options("nmax"))) {
   dev.hold()
    plot(x,y,xlim = xlim,ylim = ylim)
    text(x,y)
    x=x+rnorm(n)
    y=y+rnorm(n)
  }
}  
% end of R code
 \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Please help me out

Comment: TeX is a separate script. It can't process the code of other languages, but there are ways to add your pdf (or png) output of R into the beamer frame. Are you comfortable with it?

Comment: I would look for R-generated temporary files, in particular for `*.tex` input that is used to make the animation, and study these. Hopefully they are not deleted automatically.

Comment: @Niranjan I am comfortable with it

Comment: @DanielJames please check my answer.

Comment: @Daniel The R code doesn't run. Could you please correct it?

Answer (score 4):

I have not used R before. My conclusion after experimenting, skimming manuals and asking the internet:

> Don't use the `animation` R package. It is complicated without much
>   added value.

Instead, set an appropriate output device for plots, such as `pdf(...)`, which produces vector graphics and multipage output. After running `Rscript` on the R code, embed the PDF output as animation with `\animategraphics`.

Click to run the animation (Blink-based browsers [Chrome/Chromium, Opera] for best performance):

[image]

Besides, the original R code in the question does not run. Here is a working example, with a simple model added that prevents particles from moving past the limits. Animation frames are written to file `frames.pdf`

Run in a terminal:

```
Rscript brnMotion.R
```

File `brnMotion.R`:

```
brownianMotion <-
function(n=10,xlim=c(-20,20),ylim=c(-20,20), steps=50)
{
  x=rnorm(n) # random starting position
  y=rnorm(n)
  for (i in 1:steps) {
    plot(x,y,xlim = xlim,ylim = ylim)
    text(x,y)

    # iterate over particles
    for(k in 1:n){
      walk=rnorm(2); # random move of particle

      x[k]=x[k]+walk[1] # new position
      y[k]=y[k]+walk[2]

      # simple model (at most two rebounds) that prevents a particle
      # from moving past the limits
      if(x[k]<xlim[1]) x[k]=2*xlim[1]-x[k]
      if(x[k]>xlim[2]) x[k]=2*xlim[2]-x[k]
      if(y[k]<ylim[1]) y[k]=2*ylim[1]-y[k]
      if(y[k]>ylim[2]) y[k]=2*ylim[2]-y[k]
    }
  }
}

pdf("frames.pdf")                # output device and file name
par(xaxs="i", yaxs="i", pty="s") # square plot region
par(mai=c(0.9,0.9,0.2,0.2))      # plot margins

brownianMotion(n=20, steps=400)  # 20 particles, 400 time steps
```

LaTeX input (`pdflatex`, `lualatex` or `xelatex`):

```latex
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Brownian Motion}
  \begin{center}
  \animategraphics[width=0.5\linewidth,controls]{25}{frames}{}{}
  \end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think your idea will work but the latex code does not run on my texstudio though the r code runs and save as pdf but my attempt to open it with my Acrobat Reader DC is not not possible.

Comment: This line `\animategraphics[width=0.5\linewidth,controls]{25}{frames}{}{}` is not running in my `Latex`

Comment: Use one of `pdflatex`, `xelatex` or `lualatex`. And most importantly, an up-to-date TeX installation.

Comment: @DanielJames : I improved the particle-wall interaction model.

Comment: @DanielJames Which kind of error do you get?

Comment: Error: Missing number, treated as zero. \end{frame}

Comment: @DanielJames Does `frames.pdf` after running `Rscript` on `brnMotion.R` exist?

Comment: No, it doesn't at all. I checked it at "C:/Users/.../Documents" which is my working directory and can't get it there.

Comment: Where (in which directory) did you run `Rscript brnMotion.R`? In this directory, `frames.pdf` is created. Then, copy `frames.pdf` to the directory with the LaTeX source of the `beamer`-class presentation.

Comment: I got the `frames` as .pdf file in my r directory and put it in my beamer directory and run the beamer code you provided only to get this error messages: `Syntax Error: Couldn't find trailer dictionary Syntax Error: Couldn't read xref table`

Comment: @Daniel Do you get this error when you run `pdflatex` on the LaTeX code?

Comment: yes, I ran it on texstudio which auto selectss it as pdflatex

Comment: @Daniel Would you please put the content of the `*.log` file into your question?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by `*.log file`. can you please put it to me in a better way a layman like me would understand. I appreciate every effort you are putting to let me get this animation-of-a-thing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102267/discussion-between-alexg-and-daniel-james).

Answer (score 3):

This just extends @Alex's excellent answer by knitting the `R` code so that the `pdf` file is created in one step.

To proceed, make a file with the chunks of `R` code embedded in the `tex` file. `R` code chunks are delimited by `<<>>=` and `@`. Save the file with a `.Rnw` (R no web) extension, say `Daniel.Rnw`.

I chose to save the animation frames as `png` files because I wanted to upload the `gif`. The syntax `png("frames%d.png")` saves a sequence of files called `frame1.png` through `frame100.png`. The animated slide is just made in the usual way using `\animategraphics` from @Alex's `animate` package, which layers the `frame1.png` through `frame100.png` files to create the `pdf` output. The `R` code is wrapped in `\begin{frame} \end{frame}` to get the graphs onto a `beamer` slide.

Compile the `.Rnw` file with `pdflatex` in `RStudio` or another editor that supports `knitr` (e.g WinEdt has an add-in for this purpose).  `RStudio` will execute the `R` code to produce a `.tex` file, that integrates the output from running the `R` code with the `LaTeX` code.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{animate}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
%beginning of R code
<<code,echo=FALSE,warning=FALSE,results='hide'>>=
brownianMotion <-
function(n=10,xlim=c(-20,20),ylim=c(-20,20), steps=50)
{
  x=rnorm(n)
  y=rnorm(n)
  for (i in 1:steps) {
    plot(x,y,xlim = xlim,ylim = ylim)
    text(x,y)

    # iterate over particles
    for(k in 1:n){
      walk=rnorm(2); # random move of particle

      x[k]=x[k]+walk[1] # new position
      y[k]=y[k]+walk[2]

      # simple model for preventing a particle from moving past the limits
      if(x[k]<xlim[1]) x[k]=xlim[1]
      if(x[k]>xlim[2]) x[k]=xlim[2]
      if(y[k]<ylim[1]) y[k]=ylim[1]
      if(y[k]>ylim[2]) y[k]=ylim[2]
    }
  }
}

png("frames%d.png")              # output device and file name
par(xaxs="i", yaxs="i", pty="s") # square plot region
par(mai=c(0.9,0.9,0.2,0.2))      # plot margins

brownianMotion(n=20, steps=100)  # 20 particles, 100 time steps
dev.off()
@
% end of R code
\begin{center}
\animategraphics[autoplay,controls,palindrome,height=0.7\textheight]{5}{frames}{1}{100}%
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Probably you want the animation though, which is illustrated here: https://texblog.org/2018/02/26/making-animations-in-r-for-latex/

Comment: The link you provided is what OP wants, I guess. Can R export the animation frames as vector graphics as well?

Comment: @Alex. Yes it can save pdf. I don't have an opportunity to write a proper answer now but am happy if you or someone else can do that.

Comment: Error: Illegal parameter number in definition of \iterate. \end{frame}

Answer (score 0):

I don't know 'R', but your code (for r) resulted in some errors when I tried it online. [This](https://rdrr.io/snippets/) site provides a sample r-code. I compiled it to get a png file as the output. I named it `r.png` and used the following LaTeX code to get that image in my presentation. If you want to read more about how to add images in LaTeX, please read `graphicx` documentation. See the example below.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{A graph}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=6cm,width=\textwidth]{r} % In the {} use the appropriate file name. (case-sensitive)
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This will embed a single static image, not an animation as requested.

Comment: Yes, but this is just an example to show how to include external media files. OP can use files with different extensions. I don't have access to OPs media files (and vice-versa), but incorporating R-code in LaTeX source is not a good idea unless there is a package which enables LaTeX to process R.

Comment: OP didn't ask for including media files. Besides, `\includegraphics` would not be able to embed them anyway.

Comment: Ok, I take down my answer.